# Why is my join query not giving the expected result for three tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a problem with  3 `tables join`   I'm able to get the desired result for

`2 tables` which have `ids`: `138` , `140` , `141`

**here is my query(Getting Desired Result)**

```
SELECT distinct u.*

from jobs_applied_by_jobseeker_for_employer jbs 

Left join user_details u on u.user_id = jbs.employee_id
```

Here is a **demo**:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/360836/1

> **Now I want to join the third table to get `CONCATENATED` `skills` `String` like (html,css,mysql,php)**

**Here is the query (3 results expected, getting only 1)**

```
SELECT distinct u.*,GROUP_CONCAT(uskill.skills) skills

from jobs_applied_by_jobseeker_for_employer jbs 

Left join user_details u on u.user_id = jbs.employee_id 

left join user_skills uskill on u.user_id = uskill.user_id
```

Here is a **demo**:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/360836/3

Please help me get 3 results with `skills`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You actually are getting 3 results with `skills`, just your `GROUP_CONCAT` is showing to you as 1 row ... remove it and you will have 3 desired `IDs` ... after that change your `group concat` to have those skills in 1 row per user

Comment: @Veljko89, you are `right` but now i'm getting **each results 3 times** why demo:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/360836/20?

Comment: You need to GROUP BY!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below query can solve your problem

`SELECT u.*,GROUP_CONCAT(distinct uskill.skills) skills
 from jobs_applied_by_jobseeker_for_employer jbs 
 Left join user_details u on u.user_id = jbs.employee_id 
 left join user_skills uskill on u.user_id = uskill.user_id
 group by u.user_id`

you need to use `group by` to get different user details and add distinct keyword inside GROUP_CONTACT to get distinct skills.

Answer (score 0):

You need to Distinct with Group_Concat like this

```
        SELECT distinct u.*,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT uskill.skills) skills

        from jobs_applied_by_jobseeker_for_employer jbs 

        Left join user_details u on u.user_id = jbs.employee_id 

        left join user_skills uskill on u.user_id = uskill.USER_ID
```